# Functions with Option Parameters, or using an empty Dictionary as a Default Parameter

Tags: dictionary, swift, optional-parameters

This is what I want:

A function in swift that can take an optional parameter, so the following calls to the function `myFunc` would both work fine:

```
// assume we have a Dictionary like this
let dict=["key":"value"]

myFunc()
myFunc(dict)
```

The function `myFunc` works like this:

Any Dictionary passed into `myFunc` is merged with a Dictionary inside `myFunc`. If no Dictionary is passed into `myFunc` then the Dictionary inside `myFunc` will be used as is.

---

That's what I want to achieve in Swift. This is how I've been going about it:

It seems that you cant just omit parameters completely, but after some reading about I have been looking into default parameters. I want the parameter to be of type Dictionary, but if there is no parameter specified then I want nothing, or at least, an empty Dictionary. I have declared an empty Dictionary like so:

```
let emptyDict = Dictionary<String,String>()
```

And then I declare my function with a default parameter like so:

```
func myFunc(paramDict:Dictionary = emptyDict){ ... }
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Reference to generic type 'Dictionary' requires arguments in <...>
```

I am assuming here it is complaining because I am using an empty dictionary as a parameter.

Can anybody show me how to build a function in Swift that can function like I want `myFunc` to?

Comment: You can try (i don't have my mac with me sorry) either func myFunc(paramDict: Dictionary...) or func myFunc(paramDict: Dictionaray? = nil)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the generic types in the function parameter:

```
func myFunc(paramDict:Dictionary<String, String> = emptyDict) { }
                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Note that you don't need to define a variable to specify the default value - just do like this:

```
func myFunc(paramDict:Dictionary<String, String> = [:]) { }
```

Moreover, you may want to consider using an optional if the body of your function has a logic like "do this if the dict is provided, do that otherwise":

```
func myFunc(paramDict:Dictionary<String, String>? = nil) { }
```

it's more expressive and code is more readable in my opinion.

Comment: Yes, I prefer the use of Optionals too (great language feature imho), I will go down this route. Many thanks!